# Google maps in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have integrated google maps with the iOS app i have been building.
The map opens up when I press a button showing the location of that particular shop.
However, my question is how do I come back to the previous page from the map??
Please show me the general directions on which I should be headed for this.

Thanks

Comment: Embed the map view in navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but if your button activates a segue to another view controller that contains the map, then all you need to do is dismiss the view controller (for modal segues) or go to the previous view controller (push segues).